# How to add javascript in views in Laravel 4 Starter Site

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

i have a question related to  [Laravel 4 Starter Site](https://github.com/andrewelkins/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site)

The following is one of the view page.

```
@extends('site.layouts.default')
{{-- Web site Title --}}
@section('title')
{{{ Lang::get('site.contact_us') }}} ::

@stop

{{-- Content --}}
@section('content')

{{{ Lang::get('site.contact_us') }}}

@stop
```

In the site.layouts.default template, Jquery is included. How could i include other javascript like

```
{{ HTML::script('http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js') }}
```

into the view file? It should included after the jquery library.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```
@section('scripts')
    {{ HTML::script('...') }}
@stop
```

Anywhere in your `view` after `@extends('...')`. Because there is `@yield('scripts')` in the bottom of the layout, right after the scripts (`jQuery` and `BootStrap`).

This is another example:

```
{{-- Scripts --}}
@section('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //...
        });
    </script>
@stop
```